# Xamarin Android App TCP-IP C# Server

Tags: c#, android, tcp, xamarin.android

I'm trying to write a Xamarin Android App communicating with a C# Server via TCP-IP. The Main Goal of the App is to send DMX Values, but thats not really important for my Problem. My problem is that my App won't connect to my Server. Before I wrote the App I wrote a client only using a console aplication running directly on Windows.
Now I'm trying to connect to the Server with the following code

```
public TcpClient Client;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button connect = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        TextView connectStatus = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        connectStatus.Text = "Not Connected";

        connect.Click += (o, e) =>
        {
            Client = new TcpClient("10.0.2.2", 4711);
            if (Client.Connected)
            {
                connectStatus.Text = "Connected";
            }
        };
    }
but when i try to, the app gets stuck, asking me to quit it, when I choose wait I get a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out`exeption
```

Does anyone got a clue what this could be? I somehow have the feeling that it's not the code itself but some problem with the connection itself but i cannot think of one

Thanks for your help
Johannes

Comment: What emulator are you using? [Xamarin Android Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/) or the normal [Android SDK Emulator](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/)? If you're using XAP then you'll have to use the local network ip to send the request, otherwise you're ok with the `10.0.2.2` host ip

Comment: Using Visual Studio Emulator for Android, came with Xamarin so it's probably XAP, but I tried ealier to use my normal IP and found out about the 10.0.2.2 only by research. In the end both don't work

Comment: Tried using the normal IP now, returned:  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused

Comment: It probably got refused by your firewall, you need to open it... try disabling it only for testing, if it works just add a new entry

Comment: Ok, I'll try it tomorow thanks for your help and I Wish you a Merry Christmas

Comment: Did Not work...